# Python build not seeing openssl/ssl.h in existing location (CentOS 7)

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, centos7, python-3.10

I am attempting to build Python 3.10.5 on a CentOS 7 linux machine with the `ssl` module included. The python build succeeds but the `ssl` module fails to build.

Initially I was getting an error about python requiring OpenSSL >= 1.1.1, so I followed the instructions [here](https://cloudwafer.com/blog/installing-openssl-on-centos-7/) to install OpenSSL 1.1.1c, and verified that the installation was successful:

```
$ which openssl
/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl
```

```
$ openssl version 
OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019
```

To install Python 3.10.5 I followed the steps [here](https://linuxstans.com/how-to-install-python-centos/), replacing 3.10.2 with 3.10.5. When I ran the step:

```
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
```

I discovered that it was using the default version of OpenSSL which doesn't meet the requirement. So then I tried running:

```
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations --with-openssl="/usr/local/ssl/bin"
```

but then running `sudo make altinstall` revealed that the `ssl` and `_ssl` modules again failed to build. Going back to the output of the config command I noticed:

```
checking for openssl/ssl.h in /usr/local/ssl/bin... no
```

So then I tried running:

```
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations --with-openssl="/usr/local/ssl/include"
```

because I confirmed that this is the location of `openssl/ssl.h`. However, the output still says:

```
checking for openssl/ssl.h in /usr/local/ssl/include... no
```

which is baffling because I confirmed that is where the file lives!

```
$ ll /usr/local/ssl/include/openssl/ssl.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 111295 Oct 27 17:12 /usr/local/ssl/include/openssl/ssl.h
```

I've also tried running different variations of this command with slightly different paths in the `--with-openssl` argument, as well as including `--with-openssl-rpath=auto` and `--with-openssl-rpath=/usr/local/ssl/lib`, but it still fails to find `openssl/ssl.h`.

I saw another stackoverflow answer instruct to modify the file `~/Python-3.10.5/Modules/Setup`
to uncomment and edit the lines:

```
OPENSSL=/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl  # (Here I provided the path to my OPENSSL, which was set to some fake path before)
_ssl _ssl.c \
    -I$(OPENSSL)/include -L$(OPENSSL)/lib \
    -lssl -lcrypto
```

I did that, but still get the same error. Could the issue be related to the fact that `ssl.h` lives in `/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl` while the openssl binary lives in `/usr/local/ssl/bin`? I don't know enough to proceed from here, would really appreciate any help!

Comment: `--with-openssl` should point to the `--prefix` used to install openssl, i.e. in your case `/usr/local/ssl/`.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thank you, that worked!
How does everyone come to learn all this esoteric knowledge? Is it all passed down from the elders like this, or did folks learn things like this from school or in books? Even the blog links in my initial post to the instructions for installing OpenSSL and Python3.10 on CentOS – if I hadn't stumbled upon those posts I wouldn't have the first clue where to begin..

Comment: A more simple an standardized approach: `yum install epel-release
yum install openssl11 openssl11-devel` and `CPPFLAGS=$(pkg-config --cflags openssl11) LDFLAGS=$(pkg-config --libs openssl11) pyenv install -v 3.10.6`, see [this pyenv discussion](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2416#issuecomment-1219484906).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As you can see in the configure file, the **ssldir** should not contains **include** folder, so just use **/usr/local/ssl** is ok